# Time out on a python multiprocessing.Pool join() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, pool

I'm running an I/O intensive program by splitting it into many processes using the multithreading.Pool library. When I run the code in Jupiter on Python 3.6, I don't get any issues.

However, when I run the exact same code on a Django server, sometimes, the threads simply do not join. This is on the same input as the Jupiter notebook. I know the threads/processes are done executing because I have print statements at the beginning and end of each thread and I can see all threads are done, but they simply do not join.

My code is below :

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def run_thread(arg_one, arg_two):

    print ("Thread started")

    # Do stuff

    print ("Thread ended")

thread_list = []
pool = Pool(processes = number_of_processes, maxtasksperchild = 500)
for key, val in some_dict.items():

        # Run thread
        thread_list.append(pool.apply_async(run_thread, (arg_one, arg_two))

pool.close()
pool.join()
print ("All processed have joined.")
```

I've looked around at a few other answers and have found something like this :

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def run_thread(arg_one, arg_two):

    print ("Thread started")

    # Do stuff

    print ("Thread ended")

thread_list = []
pool = Pool(processes = number_of_processes, maxtasksperchild = 500)
for key, val in some_dict.items():

        # Run thread
        thread_list.append(pool.apply_async(run_thread, (arg_one, arg_two))


for t in thread_list:
    try:
        t.get(timeout = 5)
    except: 
        print ("Timeout occurred")

pool.close()
pool.join()
print ("All processed have joined.")
```

What I want is that if a thread runs over the timeout interval, simply kill it and move on. In the above solution, I still have to wait till all the threads run to get to the final print statement that says "All processes have joined".

Please do pardon my usage of thread/process. I mean process in every case.